# How to reduce enum definition indentation?

Tags: indentation, c++

With my actual configuration, an `enum` definition looks like this:

```
enum    Toto
    {
        foo,
        bar
    }
```

Spaces are by packs of 4 instead of 2 because I set 4 as default indentation space for C/C++.

I would like to align brackets with `enum` keyword WITHOUT reducing space between them and enum list, like this:

```
enum    Toto
{
    foo,
    bar
}
```

I already done a similar thing by totally canceling `namespace` indentation, with the following Elisp line:

```
(c-set-offset 'innamespace 0)
```

But I don't know if something similar is possible for `enum`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adopt the same kind of solution as for your namespace definition, except you should use the `brace-list-open` identifier.

```lisp
(c-set-offset 'brace-list-open 0)
```

After this setup, your code indents like this (with 2-space indentation):

```c++
enum Toto
{
  foo,
  bar
}
```

**NB:** You can find the correct indentation identifier using <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd> ([`c-show-syntactic-information`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Syntactic-Analysis.html#Syntactic-Analysis)) on any line of a C++ buffer. It will perform the syntactic analysis of the line and display the results. For example, when used in the `{` line above, it will highlight the first character of `enum`, and indicate in the minibuffer:

```
Syntactic analysis: ((brace-list-open 1))
```

**Warning:** Judging by the identifier name (`brace-list-open`), it might well be used for syntactic constructs other than `enum`. So you should expect side-effects.